Is there any way to trim the URL of an autofill suggestion?
I am working with Chrome on macOS, but the question applies to any browser on any OS.
Often when I type in a URL, it autofills with the URL I want with extra query/route parameters from my most recent interaction with that site. For example, if I want to access https://math.stackexchange.com, it might suggest to autofill my user page rather than just the bare URL.
Is there a quick way to autofill just to the root (i.e. right after the TLD, e.g. .com) of a suggestion in the address bar?
My current methods are:

manually clicking the right spot, use ⌘+Shift+Right Arrow to select extra chars, then delete
⌘+Right Arrow to jump to the end, ⌘+Shift+Left Arrow to select the entire string, ⌥+Shift+Right Arrow to deselect up to the root, then delete extra chars

I would like this to be a general solution, so preferably not via blacklisting every extraneous suggestion manually.
